# Rspec controllertest: collection object is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working on a Course application made of chapters. Each chapter has a quiz with questions and answers.

Each question can only have one correct answer. I want to test this rule with RSpec.

In my Answers controller test I wrote a test:

```
  it "does not create a new correct answer when there is already a correct answer" do
        answer2 = Answer.create(title: "correct answer", is_correct: true, question_id: @question.id) 
        @question.answers << answer2
        post :create, question_id: @question.id, answer: { title: "new answer", is_correct: true }
        expect(Answer.count).to eq(1)
```

In this test, I want to make sure that no new answer is created when the question.answers collection already has an answer with the is_correct property set to true.

However, my test is failing. When I check the code in the create action of my answers controller and check that question has at least one answer in it's question.answers collection, it seems that:

```
question
```

returns an empty array

```
=> []
```

Why is the question.answers collection empty, when in the test I added an answer to the question's answers collection?

```
@question.answers << answer2
```

Comment: well how can I pass a question with an answer to my answers#create action method. Thanks for your help

Comment: shouldn't you save @question after the answer assignment? in your controller, question gets loaded from db. By the way, you shouldn't test that inside the controller, since the controller is not responsible for that logic, you should test that in your answer specs, an answer is not valid if the question it belongs already have a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for sure, but I can provide suggestions to find the actual problem.

There are two things you should try to isolate it, here :

1. make sure `@question` from your test and the one in your action are indeed the same (you can check its `#id`, or even its `#object_id`)
2. in tests (and indeed, everywhere you do not check validation status then), you should use `#create!` rather than `#create`, so that failing to create the record will trigger an obvious exception.

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks for the testing tips. In the meantime I'm using a validates callback to prevent muliple answers to a question having the  is_correct attribute set to true: validates_uniqueness_of :is_correct, conditions: -> { where(is_correct: true) }